# How to know inside valueChanges.subscribe(...) if the value was changed by an user interaction or by patchValue(...)

Tags: angular

In angular 2 I have a reactive form with two select controls (for example, country and province) and I subscribe to the valueChanges of the country control to re-load the list of provinces, and I want to know inside valueChanges.subscribe(...) if the country was changed by the user or by patchValue(...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pristine`, `dirty` or `touched` from `AbstractControl`.

There is also an example in the [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#why-check-dirty-and-touched)

For more details have a look at the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)

Answer (score 0):

`control.dirty` solved my problem